# Implementing an environment with user-defined sectioning and Title

Tags: environments

I have been using the following

```
\newtheorem{myDefn}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{myTeor}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{myCorl}{Corollary}[myTeor]
```

Whilst doing the numbering per section, I find the scheme problematic.

Consider the following.  The numbering gets me confused because they will not follow the sectioning numbers when looking them up.  For instance, one might think that `Definition 1.1.3` is associated with subsection `1.1.3`.  Furthermore, I might end up with numerous numbering subdivisions such as `Corollary 1.1.1.1`.

Would much prefer having the possibility of defining the identification by using some text, making the environment more adaptable.

For instance, having the output be

```
Definition ID TITLE

Text
```

Where `ID` some identifier, whilst `TITLE` is a descriptor.

As example, consider

```
Definition GCHQ The Doughnut
```

where `GCHQ` is the Identifier and `The Doughnut` is the Title.

See example of my sectioning problem below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Ramanujan}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter {This is an introduction
  to some topic}

\section{Some Section}

Some Text Here

\begin{mfDefn} This Definition
A \textit{prime number} is a natural number greater than 1 that has no
positive divisors other than 1 and itself.
\end{myDefn}

\begin{myDefn} That Definition
A \textit{prime number} is a natural number greater than 1 that has no
positive divisors other than 1 and itself.
\end{myDefn}

\subsection{Test}

\begin{myDefn} Another Definition
A \textit{prime number} is a natural number greater than 1 that has no
positive divisors other than 1 and itself.
\end{myDefn}

\begin{myTeor} This Theorem
A \textit{prime number} is a natural number greater than 1 that has no
positive divisors other than 1 and itself.
\end{myTeor}

\begin{myCorl} This Corollary
A \textit{prime number} is a natural number greater than 1 that has no
positive divisors other than 1 and itself.
\end{myCorl}

\end{document}
```

Comment: theorems all have an optional title you have not used. `\begin{myTeor}[Pythagoras]`

Comment: The sectioning would be the biggest hurdle from what I have seen.

Comment: you are defining theorems to be numbered per section, if you would rather them be numbered per subsection just replace `[section]` by `[subsection]` (if that isn't what you mean, I don't understand the question)

Comment: Rather than ending up with complicated numbering hierarchy, I am entertaining the idea of having an identifier instead of the numbering system, similar to the optional title you have mentioned.  For instance `\begin{mfDefn}[ID][This Definition]`.

Comment: I do not see `[subsubsection]` would work very well because all upper level sections would have very long numbers with dots to match the `subsubsection` numbering.

Comment: don't be too inventive, it will just confuse readers. Find a book you like and look what it does,

Comment: I do not see how having a user identifier is too inventive.  It is just a replacement for the `1.1.1.1.1.1`.

Comment: Sierpiński used to be very inventive.

Comment: I am doing this for myself rather than for readers.

Comment: Couldn't you just use different punctuation before the theorem number? Or you could use something other than Arabic numerals to distinguish things e.g. 'theorems 1.A, 1.2.B and 1.2.1.D' or whatever. The problem with an ID is it gives the reader no clue as to where it might be in the text (earlier? later? three chapters back?). If the result is just for you, why not stick to electronic and use hyperlinks?

Comment: The only way you'll get "numerous numbering subdivisions such as Corollary 1.1.1.1" would be if you don't follow a normal definition where the construction of the number is tied to the reset counter. For example, if you reset the corollary counter with every theorem usage, but have the corollary counter constructed with a section number prefix (say). Then, yes, you *may* end up with duplicate numbered constructions. Your current definitions in the question doesn't do that; you will only have **one** Corollary 1.1.1.1 in your document, since the counter is tied to `myTheor`.